# No such file to load, Model/Lib naming conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, namespaces, module, webrick

I'm working on a Rails application. I have a Module called Animals. Inside this Module is a Class with the same name as one of my Models (Dog).

show_animal action:

```
def show_animal
  require 'Animals/Bear.rb' #Works
  require 'Animals/Dog.rb' #Fails
end
```

So the first require definitely works, the seconds fails.
MissingSourceFile (no such file to load -- Animals/Dog.rb):

I noticed that Dog.rb is the same file name as one of my models, is that what's causing this? I'm using Webrick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the full path:

```
require File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'Animals', 'Dog.rb')
```

Comment: just had a similar problem, but I didn't have any naming conflicts, rails just didn't want to LOAD the file, go figure